# Using Ruby + OAuth to access Yelp API

Tags: ruby, oauth, oauth-ruby

I just getting started with OAuth, and I tried to make a small client to connect to some webservices... I tried twitter and it worked like a charm, however, I also tried to access Yelp V2 API (following their Python example) but I always get back as an answers:
HTTP 400 Bad Request

Missing parameter: oauth_consumer_key

Here's my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'

CONSUMER_KEY = "MY_CONSUMER_KEY"
SECRET = "MY_CONSUMER_SECRET"
TOKEN = "MY_TOKEN"
TOKEN_SECRET = "MY_TOKEN_SECRET"


consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new( CONSUMER_KEY,SECRET, {:site => "http://api.yelp.com", :signature_method => "HMAC-SHA1", :scheme => :header})

access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new( consumer, TOKEN,TOKEN_SECRET)

p access_token.get("/v2/search?location=new+york").body
```

Regardless to say, that code works with twitter API without any problem (I actually followed twitter's example code)

Cheers and thanks in advance,
Ze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :query_string instead of :header and everything will work (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

Same code, using [Signet](http://signet.rubyforge.org/):

```
require 'signet/oauth_1/client'
client = Signet::OAuth1::Client.new(
  :consumer_key =>        'MY_CONSUMER_KEY',
  :consumer_secret =>     'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET',
  :access_token_key =>    'MY_TOKEN_KEY',
  :access_token_secret => 'MY_TOKEN_SECRET'
)
response = client.fetch_protected_resource(
  :uri => 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=new+york'
)
# The Rack response format is used here
status, headers, body = response
p body
```

As per the [Yelp documentation](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication), the OAuth parameters do **not** have to be passed in the query string.  The fact that the accepted answer resolved the issue indicates to me that there's probably a bug in the `oauth` gem causing this.